# Using array as search criteria in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, crud

I've got an array of, say, phone numbers:

```
var numberArray = ["9023452112", "3023093039"];
```

How can I use this to search Mongo documents?

```
User.find({ number: numberArray }, function(err, result)...);
```

Mongoose doesn't seem to like this.

Comment: I assume you mean you tried "numbers" rather than "numberArray"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator which looks for documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array:

```
var numberArray = ["9023452112", "3023093039"];
User.find({ "number": { "$in": numberArray} }, function(err, result){...});
```

Comment: Works great! Now another quick followup: What if I wanted two of these? Ie. Phone numbers in this array, OR emails in this second array?

Comment: @opticon Not sure if i got you right, which second array? If you had another field which stores email values then the same concept applies; create another array with possible email values which you can then use as the **`$in`** operator against the email field.

Comment: @chridam Sounds like he wants: `User.find( {"number": {"$in": numberArray}, "email": {"$in": emailArray}}, ...);`

Comment: @Tony Thanks for the clarification, I concur though was a but unsure since they mentioned _emails in this second array_ and was wondering if the array also had emails.